# Visual Studio : Disable CodeLens lync (Skype Enterprise) integration?

Tags: visual-studio, lync, skype-for-business, codelens

The enterprise I work for recently started using Skype Enterprise. Our setup seems very problematic, we have two domains, two seperate email/mailbox and Lync/Skype Enterprise doesn't like it and goes into endless loops on some features (creating Outlook meetings, for example).

One of those feature is the CodeLens / Source Control / Lync integration. If I accidentally click on someone's name, Visual Studio (2017) becomes unresponsive and the Skype Enterprise window pops up but does nothing. Even if I close / minimize the window, Visual Studio is still unresponsive. I have to close Skype or kill it's process. 
Of course, the problem doesn't occur when Skype Enterprise is not running.

So I decided to not use Skype Enterprise and that was OK for a while, but now more and more people want me to get on skype... meaning I have to keep it running now.

I've submitted the problem to our internal TI Support service and their current solution is to disable Skype / Outlook integration extension in Outlook, works for outlook freezes we had but doesn't do anything for Visual Studio.

All that being said. I know how to disable CodeLens but I like it's features (source control integration) and would rather not disable it, if possible. However, CodeLens Lync integration (Having "Call" shortcuts in Visual studio), I don't care about. I'd like to disable only that integration since it's problematic. But looking at CodeLens options... i don't see a way to disable that specific communication.

Anyone has any idea? A specific registry key maybe?

[image: CodeLens Options]

Comment: Same problem here - any luck finding the result?

Comment: Our IT department fixed my skype (lync) issues by deleting and recreating my user's windows profile on this computer. Since that has fixed the freezes, i stopped looking for a way to disable that function of CodeLens.